# If $3 \mid a^2+b^2$, then show that $9 \mid ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $3 \mid a^2+b^2$, then show that $9 \mid ab$.

If $3$ divides $a^2+b^2$ I have that $a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Looking at the squares it seems that starting from $9$ for every third I’ll get a remainder $0$. Also squares mod $3$ are only $0$ or $1$ so I must have $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and $b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} $, but still how does this imply the result we’re after?

Comment: If $3\mid a^2$, then $3\mid a$; similarly $3\mid b$, so $9\mid ab$

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384373/does-euclids-lemma-apply-to-squared-numbers) answer your question?

Comment: Short answer, $\forall ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, either $n^2 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$ or $n^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  From the constraints of the problem, you can not have either $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ or $b^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a^2\equiv0\pmod3$ means  $3\mid a^2$, which implies  $3\mid a$ (by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma))
;

similarly $3\mid b$, so $9\mid ab$.

Comment: You may add it is Euclid's lemma since OP doesn't seem to know this property.

Comment: Ok, @zwim; I did

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).